# Change a non-JSON file into a true JSON file preferably with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, object

I'm trying to use a JSON file in Angular, but the reference file isn't true JSON. What's the best way to access it, and parse it, into true JSON, to be used?

I'm trying to access notTrue.json in a controller in angular.js, like in the file structure below. And parse notTrue.json into a real JSON format.

Example file structure:

```
index.html
js (folder)
 - angular.js
 - notTrue.json
 - etc
css (folder)
img (folder)
```

Example non-JSON format, notTrue.json file:

```
var Foo = [{
    'bar': 'Hello World',
    'subItem': {
        'phone1': '(555) 543-213',
        'email': 'foo@bar.com'
    }
}, {
    'bar': 'Goodnight Moon',
    'subItem': {
        'phone1': '(555) 521-3344',
        'email': 'foo2@bar.com'
    }
}];
```

I want to get it into a proper JSON format, like below:

```
[{
    "bar": "Hello World",
    "subitem": {
        "phone1": "(555) 543-213",
        "email": "foo@bar.com"
    }
}, {
    "bar": "Goodnight Moon",
    "subitem": {
        "phone1": "(555) 521-3344",
        "email": "foo2@bar.com"
    }
}]
```

Comment: The first is not JSON format, it is an object. JSON is a string. Are you sure you didn't want to say that `Foo` is a string? Can you clarify?

Comment: As evil as it is, `eval` might do what you need. Seems like you're saying you have some arbitrary Javascript text you need to interpret, which is what `eval` does. That being said, you don't even have JSON like data, with the `var Foo =`, you just have javascript. If that part is well known, you can eval and then access foo to retrieve the object. Otherwise, the real answer is to clean up your data sources. It should be sanitized before it hits the client.

Comment: @trincot - yes, the first is an object. The 'JSON' file its from is not correctly formatted to begin with. (Not real JSON).

Comment: So you did convert the not-JSON file to an object called `Foo`. I am lost as to what is your question then, because converting `Foo` to valid JSON is trivial.

Comment: @trincot - the external file is the Foo object. It's not in local files. I'm trying to grab it, then parse it into valid JSON. That's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `notTrue.json` file is static, in the sense that it is already there when the user accesses `index.html` and will not change during the user's use of the application, then it is best to include `notTrue.json` via a `script` tag, before loading `angular.js`, like this:

```
<script src="js/notTrue.json"></script>
<script src="js/angularjs"></script>
```

Then you will have access to the `Foo` object in your application. The following code illustrates this by outputting the JSON format on screen:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myControler">
   <pre>{{json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myControler', function($scope, $window) {
        // window.Foo was defined when loading notTrue.js 
        // Convert it to JSON string (pretty printed)
        $scope.json = JSON.stringify($window.Foo, null, 4);
    });
</script>
```

In the above example, the on-page output will be:

```
[
    {
        "bar": "Hello World",
        "subItem": {
            "phone1": "(555) 543-213",
            "email": "foo@bar.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "bar": "Goodnight Moon",
        "subItem": {
            "phone1": "(555) 521-3344",
            "email": "foo2@bar.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Note that the `pre` tag and the extra arguments to the `JSON.stringify` method are used to get the JSON string pretty printed. But this is not essential to your question.

**Dynamically loading `notTrue.js`**

If on the other hand, you want to defer loading `notTrue.js` until some event takes place, because its contents might change between page load and that event, then you could use `$http.get`.

In the following example, the file is loaded upon a button click, and the JSON format is output on screen:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myControler">
   <button ng-click="load('js/notTrue.json')">Load</button>
   <pre>{{json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myControler', function($scope, $http) {
        // Define what should happen on button click:
        $scope.load = function(file) {
            $http.get(file).then(function(response) {
                // Extract from the retrieved file contents
                // the part between the first "=" and 
                // final (optional) semi-colon
                var txt = response.data.replace(/^.*?=([\S\s]*?);?\s*$/, '$1');
                // Evaluate that text, adding brackets to avoid misinterpretation
                // when text starts with opening brace.
                var Foo = eval('(' + txt + ')');
                // and convert to JSON string (pretty printed)
                $scope.json = JSON.stringify(Foo, null, 4);
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

The output is the same as with the first solution.

Note that with this method, the loaded file must reside on the same server, which I understand is your case.

Only go for this solution if the first one does not suit your needs.

You will want to add checks and deal with potential errors for when the file is not found, does not have the expected format, etc.

Finally, be careful with using `eval`: only use it when you trust the source, which I believe is the case here.

Comment: Thanks @trincot, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The first example is plain javascript code - and you say you trust the source.

If this code has been returned in response to a server request, and can access it as `responseText`, say, then

```
var JSONtext = JSON.stringify( eval(responseText.replace(/[^=]*=/,"")));
```

should do the job. (The regular expression replacement takes out the variable definition).